# Does a weapon unlock, unlock that weapon for every class?

Tags: planetside-2

I'll try to clarify with an example.

Let say I buy a Forward Grip certification for the AF-19 Mercenary under the "Weapon" tree of the Engineer, will it also be available for the Light Assault class, since they have that same default weapon? (AF-19 Mercenary).

Since Certifications costs some point, I wanted to know if I'd have to buy each of them maybe twice.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they will have the same attachments. If you want to switch to a different carbine you have to buy them again, though.

Comment: That's surprising, I assumed I'd have to buy the same thing twice just because it's on different classes. Nice to know.